# In how many ways can you put $m$ distinct objects into $n$ distinct boxes where each box has a capacity of either $3$ or $4$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can you put $m$ distinct objects into $n$ distinct boxes where each box has a capacity of either $3$ or $4$ such that $3n \lt m \lt 4n$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks saulspatz for the suggestion I'm still new to stack so I don't have much knowledge about how it operates. I'll reconsider my question and add some more details later.

Comment: Pick which boxes received the $4$ objects., then for each of the boxes which received the four objects, pick which four of those objects they were... then for each of the remaining boxes pick which three of the objects they each received.  There are $m-3n$ boxes that will receive four objects and the remaining $4n-m$ of which will receive three objects.

Answer (score 1):

There would be $\dbinom{n}{m-3n}$ ways to choose which of the $n$ boxes wound up with 4 items.

There are $\dfrac{m!}{(3!)^{4n-m}(4!)^{m-3n}}$ ways to assign distinct items to the boxes in order.

I believe there would be $\dbinom{n}{m-3n}\dfrac{m!}{(3!)^{4n-m}(4!)^{m-3n}}$ total ways to distribute the objects to the boxes.

Comment: Wait why did you put 4n-m in power of 3! ?

Comment: Suppose $m=3n+k$. Then there are $k=m-3n$ boxes that need 4 items and $n-k=4n-(3n+k) = 4n-m$ boxes that needs 3 items.

Comment: I feel there is error in solution :::: But we can have boxes with 2 object and more boxes with 4 objects . e.g m=14 , n=4 then the only case considered in your solution is 3,3,4,4 and there arrangements but another possibility 2,4,4,4 and arrangements of these , is missing in your solution.

Comment: According to me solution will be $$\sum_{0\le r_1,r_2,...r_n \le 4} (\frac{m!}{r_1!r_2!r_3!....r_n!})$$ and $$r_1+r_2+r_3+.....r_n=m$$

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com The OP states that every box has a "capacity" of 3 or 4 items, but from the context, it appears that the word "capacity" is being used to describe the exact number of items in the box, not the maximum number of items in the box. I think the OP just used the wrong word. If you would like to supply your answer, feel free, but that does not diminish the correctness of my answer based on my interpretation of the OP's question.

Comment: It's TRUE I am going by the language of question that in any box number of objects can le less than or equal to 4. In same line I have written the answer above. But since 2 days the one who has put question is not putting comment what he wants that not clarifying on language of question.

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com I agree. I am not saying you are wrong. I am saying my answer is correct up to the assumptions I made.